# SQL Change an UPDATE to skip duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

[table] is a table which I parse once a minute, and I am updating the oldest records with 'in progress'. When I am done processing, I delete the 'in progress' records and start over. My **rare** issue is when I have the same record trying to get imported twice in the same 50 batch. I would like to change this.

I have this update of [table]

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  TOP 50  [Status]
FROM            [table] 
ORDER BY        [ImportDate] ASC)
UPDATE cte SET [Status] = 'IN PROGRESS';
```

I would like to change it in a way that if there are 2 (or more) records in the [table] with the same unique ID, then just get the oldest one, just one record all the time, so it's like an `update distinct uniquecolumn order by importdate`

Note unique id is unique in the original database, in my table is not unique, my table has no indexes, no constraint or anything, since it is empty almost all the time, except when we get data dumped in it

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: You can probably leverage ROW_NUMBER for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One wasy would be to rank order all [status] values by ImportDate and date the oldest using ROW_NUMBER().

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TOP 50 * FROM
    (
        SELECT  [Status], ImportDate,
                RN= ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Status ORDER BY ImportDate)
        FROM    [table] 
    )AS X       
    WHERE RN=1
    ORDER BY ImportDate  
)
UPDATE cte SET [Status] = 'IN PROGRESS'
```

Comment: This works but I think I would skip the top 50 cte so you don't have to number the entire table and then ignore all but 50 rows. Also the top query needs an order by.

Comment: You can't order by in a subquery so you may not get the lowest date of dups if you only bring back the top 50 first and then check for dups.

Comment: But without an order by top 50 * is free to return whatever 50 rows it wants.

Comment: That is true, without an ID the data would likely return in natural order or the order of an existing clustered index. I agree that It is not an ideal query to use without specifying a unique identifier.

Comment: And since you have top you can use order by in that cte.

Comment: PARTITION BY Status ORDER BY ImportDate - you mean PARTITION BY UniqueColumnName ORDER BY ImportDate. Right?

Comment: @Ash - The question asked about ranking status by date to take the status with the lowest date. The question did not include a unique identifier.

Comment: Does close to what I wanted, but, as Sean pointed out, sort is an issue. Made a new stackoverflow question, with new approach, because the original ImportDate sort is very important

Comment: @Ash - Simply add the order by right after RN=1 and you will be good to go.

Comment: @SeanLange - Good tip, I updated the answer with an order by. Sorry for the lag, I was away for a bit.