# SQL Update duplicates ordered by specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

[table] is a table which I parse once a minute, and I am updating the oldest records with 'in progress'. When I am done processing, I delete the 'in progress' records and start over. My **rare** issue is when I have the same record trying to get imported twice in the same 50 batch. I would like to change this.

I have this update of [table]

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  TOP 4   [Status]
FROM            [table] 
ORDER BY        [ImportDate] ASC)
UPDATE cte SET [Status] = 'IN PROGRESS';
```

I would like to add a second update (99% of cases would not trigger, and when it would, it will most certainly will be 3 records maximum), where any of these 50 `IN PROGRESS` records that are dupes based on a column called `UniqueId`, would be updated back to `New` (the oldest record would keep the value `IN PROGRESS`, the newest ones would be `NEW`)

Example:

**before**

| UniqueId | ImportDate | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2022-04-22 | new |
| b | 2022-04-23 | new |
| b | 2022-04-24 | new |
| c | 2022-04-25 | new |
| d | 2022-04-26 | new |
| e | 2022-04-27 | new |

**after**

| UniqueId | ImportDate | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2022-04-22 | in progress |
| b | 2022-04-23 | in progress |
| b | 2022-04-24 | in progress |
| c | 2022-04-25 | in progress |
| d | 2022-04-26 | new |
| e | 2022-04-27 | new |

**desired 2nd update's result**

| UniqueId | ImportDate | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2022-04-22 | in progress |
| b | 2022-04-23 | in progress |
| b | 2022-04-24 | **new** |
| c | 2022-04-25 | in progress |
| d | 2022-04-26 | new |
| e | 2022-04-27 | new |

Note unique id is unique in the original database, in my table is not unique, my table has no indexes, no constraints or anything, since it is empty almost all the time, except when we get data dumped in it

How can I do that?

Comment: So you need in bigger date get updated based on you UniqueId? Why you have top 4? That is only for example?

Comment: You asked almost the same identical question earlier today. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72014175/sql-change-an-update-to-skip-duplicates

Comment: All you need to do from the answer from Ross Bush in your previous question is to add an order by to the top 50 cte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can try to use `Row_NUMBER` window function twice instead of `TOP`, the first `Row_NUMBER` window generate number of row which can filter instead `TOP`

Another `Row_NUMBER` window to update first `ImportDate` each `UniqueId`

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  [Status], 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UniqueId ORDER BY ImportDate) rn1,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ImportDate) rn2
        FROM  [table]
    ) t1    
    WHERE rn1 = 1 AND rn2 BETWEEN 1 AND 4
)
UPDATE cte 
SET [Status] = 'IN PROGRESS'
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=d89bb9df27238c6de5b47381cd36dd26)